# how string literal can be used to obtain a charcter in itself

Tags: c, string

Iam confused with following please describe me how the following works

```
char ch[10] = "bayant";
char c  =  "bayant"[2] ;
printf("%c",c);
```

It  produces y but how it is possible?

Comment: I would like to point out that - at least with GCC - the value of C is evaluated at compile time, thus the whole string "bayant" is not present in memory nor in the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ch[2]
```

Is only syntactic sugar for

```
*(ch + 2)
```

and since addition is commutative, there is no difference with

```
*(2 + ch)
```

That's the same meaning with other array types, of course.

Example:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// syntactic sugar
printf("%i\n", 3[array]);
printf("%i\n", array[3]);
// for
printf("%i\n", *(array + 3));
printf("%i\n", *(3 + array));
```

In your example

```
printf("%c\n",*( 2 + "bayant")); 
printf("%c\n", *("bayant" + 2));
```

I know it can result strange, but that's how C works.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing starts with 0.

```
"bayant"[0] //b
"bayant"[1] //a
"bayant"[2] //y
"bayant"[3] //a
"bayant"[4] //n
"bayant"[5] //t
```

[image: Structure of array]

Read more about arrays [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to write all that, you can only write, for example:

```
printf( "%c", "0123456789"[8] );
```

and you shall see the `8` being printed out. The reason for this can be thought as following:

Whenever your programme encounters anything inside double-quotes, i.e. `"0123456789"`, the computer allocates some piece of memory, long enough to hold this new data, and fills the memory with this new data.

In this case, it will allocate a piece of memory that is 10 + 1 (1 for the string-terminating zero) bytes long, fills them like:

```
'0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '\0'
 ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th  .   .   .   .  11th
```

After that, it grabs the memory location of the very first element, and returns it back to you. In this case, the memory location of the `'0'` will be returned to you. You may as well call it the *pointer*, and you may as well call this data-set an *array*.

Now what would happen if you were to append an array-name (which **is** the memory location of the first element) with a `[0]`, or prefix it with a `*`? It would return you the very first element in it, right? `"0123456789"` evaluates into the memory location of the first element as I said above, so logically, `"0123456789"[0]` also gives you the first element in it. Same for the remaining elements...

Answer (score 0):

In `"bayant"[2]`, `"bayant"` give its base address, which means it can be treated like a `const char *` variable, so

```
"bayant"[0] --> 'b'
"bayant"[1] --> 'a'
......
```

In another words, `"bayant"[2]` more or less equals

```
const char *cp = "bayant";
cp[2];
```

I known it looks strange, but it is how C syntax works, part of it just strange.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are similar to base address of the string. So if you want index of 
`"bayant"[2]` it is similar to `ch[2]` which is nothing but 'y'.

This is because string literal is a constant address, so it is similar to accessing the array contents by using pointer *(ch + 2).